# single indexed multiple arrays to one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a number of arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => A-I-only )
Array ( [0] => B-III-only )
Array ( [0] => C-I-and-II-only )
Array ( [0] => D-II-and-III-only )
Array ( [0] => E-I,-II,-III )
```

I want to put each array's first row in one array, like this:

```
Array( [0] => A-I-only [1] =>B-III-only [2] => C-I-and-II-only [3] => D-II-and-III-only [4] => E-I,-II,-III )
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please be more explanatory on your question.

Comment: i want to combine it in single arrayArray ( [0] => A-I-only )
Array ( [0] => B-III-only )
Array ( [0] => C-I-and-II-only )
Array ( [0] => D-II-and-III-only )
Array ( [0] => E-I,-II,-III )

Comment: are these separate arrays or members of the same array?

Comment: @shruti Please select edit on your question and extend it.

Comment: yes these all are the members of same array i.e options

Comment: Array( [0] => A-I-only [1] =>B-III-only [2] => C-I-and-II-only [3] => D-II-and-III-only [4] => E-I,-II,-III )    i want this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can use `array merge` function. Like:

```
$array = array_merge($array1,$array2,...);
```

Please note though that this would not work properly if your common indices were of string type (there would be a value overriding). Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for more.

Comment: Op is specifying indices in output, not sure if this question is correct then.

Comment: This one seems to be working, as there are numeric indices, and an appending will take place. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $array0 = array('A-I-only');
> $array1 = array('B-III-only');
> $array2 = array('C-I-and-II-only');
> $array3 = array('D-II-and-III-only');
> $array4 = array('E-I,-II,-III');
> ```
>
> $result = **array_merge**($array0, $array1, $array2, $array3,
>   $array4);

```
print_r($result);
```

**The Above code will give result as below**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A-I-only
    [1] => B-III-only
    [2] => C-I-and-II-only
    [3] => D-II-and-III-only
    [4] => E-I,-II,-III
)
```

Comment: Please brief what is in $result2.

Or provide more code.

Comment: The task is.. i have to upload a file.. the file contains questions and answers (4 options each) as well as correct answers..i have uploaded a file and see its contents through fget..now i want to save questions and its options in database.. $result2 contains all the file data containing all options of all questions .$options=explode(" ",$result2);    when i explode $result2 the output is....         .Array ( [0] => A-I-only )
Array ( [0] => B-III-only )
Array ( [0] => C-I-and-II-only )
Array ( [0] => D-II-and-III-only )
Array ( [0] => E-I,-II,-III )

Comment: this is the options of one question when i print $result2..this shows... Array
(
    [0] => A-I-only
    [1] => B-III-only
    [2] => C-I-and-II-only
    [3] => D-II-and-III-only
    [4] => E-I,-II,-III
)

Comment: So you want like this : option1 of all questions in one single array, and option2 of all questions in another array, and so on right?